# Is there a way in Android Studio to use Ctrl+tab to navigate to recently used editor?

Tags: android-studio

Is there a way in Android Studio to use Ctrl+tab to navigate to recently used editor?

Comment: `Ctrl+Tab` does switch tabs to the most recently used tab.. Holding `Ctrl` then shows the list of open tabs which you can cycle through using the `Tab` key..

Comment: Not on my settings... Odd. Can you say to what shortcut are the ctrl+tab are set in your ide?

Comment: It's called Switcher. You can modify it from Preferences->Keymap->Other->Switcher

Comment: Putting this as an answer...

Comment: You can use Alt + Left / Alt + Right to navigate through your files as you moved forward (e.g. goto definition, Alt + Left for going back).

Comment: Yes... But this is not navigating through editor tabs. Anyway... question answered by @akash93.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio has two types of switching methods, as can be seen on the keymap settings:

1. "Recent Editors" - shows a list of recent editors but you need to leave the ctrl key and click up/down keys then another click to select the relevant editor.
2. "Switcher" - shows a quick list of recent editors. Setting Ctrl+tab to this will behave like many of the other editors in the market: Notepad++, Visual Studio, Eclipse ADT, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ctrl+E to list last opened or edited files, use arrow key to move up and down.

Comment: Read the question. This solution is not good because it requires 3 clicks minimum. Not a solution.

Comment: The solution (as @akash93 noted above) is set the ctrl+tab link to "switcher" in keymap.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + tab is already doing that! it shows the switcher having the most recently used editor highlighted, after releasing Ctrl key it will switch to the editor, if you keep holding the Ctrl then there are 2 ways to navigate through the switcher, either by Tab, or by up and down arrows with Enter.

Another way is Navigate-> Back/Forward which will move cursor between edit locations in same file and move along to other files, the default key mapping for those are (Alt +Ctrl + Left)/(Alt +Ctrl +Right), which conflicts with windows mapping, Personally I am using Eclipse key mapping, so they are (Alt + left)/(Alt + right).

Don't forget that you can change any key mapping or add an extra key mapping from File->Settings->Keymap